# HTTP request failing – but only when run through Cocoapods

Tags: ruby, http, ssl, curl, cocoapods

I publish a pod with the following spec:

```rb
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name         = "AirTurnInterface"
  s.version      = "4.7.0-b.6"
  s.summary      = "snip"

  s.description  = "snip"

  s.license = { :file => 'LICENSE', :type => 'AirTurn' }

  s.homepage     = "snip"

  s.author             = { "Nick Brook" => "snip@airturn.com" }

  s.ios.deployment_target = "11.0"

  s.frameworks = 'CoreBluetooth', 'GameController', 'Security', 'UIKit'

  s.source       = { :http => "https://airturn.com/framework/test/AirTurnInterface.#{s.version}.zip" }

    s.vendored_frameworks = "Framework-dynamic/AirTurnInterface.xcframework"

end
```

This can be tested by putting the following in a file named `test.podspec` and running `pod spec lint test.podspec`.

Until recently, this worked fine. Now, running `pod spec lint` fails when downloading the zip with the error:

> curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)

It also provides the curl command used:

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/curl/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/9j/jqc5qhp922b7c8jhrvkh7h8m0000gn/T/d20221021-48752-1fqts5p/file.zip https://airturn.com/framework/test/AirTurnInterface.4.7.0-b.6.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2 -A 'CocoaPods/1.11.3 cocoapods-downloader/1.5.1'
```

The strange thing is, this command works when run directly, it only fails when run from Cocoapods (ruby). I've also tried just performing the command from a simple ruby script, which works fine. Something about Cocoapods is causing the command to fail. I've modified Cocoapods (`gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.5.1/lib/cocoapods-downloader/http.rb`) to pass `-v` to curl, which provides the following output:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 35.209.185.188:443...
* Connected to airturn.com (35.209.185.188) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [88 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [187 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
{ [19 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [4039 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
{ [264 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [52 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [52 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.airturn.com
*  start date: Oct  5 00:07:55 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Jan  3 00:07:54 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "airturn.com" matched cert's "airturn.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multiplexing
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
} [5 bytes data]
* h2h3 [:method: GET]
* h2h3 [:path: /framework/test/AirTurnInterface.4.7.0-b.6.zip]
* h2h3 [:scheme: https]
* h2h3 [:authority: airturn.com]
* h2h3 [user-agent: 'CocoaPods/1.11.3 cocoapods-downloader/1.5.1']
* h2h3 [accept: */*]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x15580f600)
} [5 bytes data]
> GET /framework/test/AirTurnInterface.4.7.0-b.6.zip HTTP/2
> Host: airturn.com
> user-agent:  'CocoaPods/1.11.3 cocoapods-downloader/1.5.1'
> accept: */*
> 
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
{ [265 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
{ [265 bytes data]
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
{ [5 bytes data]
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
} [5 bytes data]
* HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Connection #0 to host airturn.com left intact
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
```

Forcing http1.1 with --http1.1 doesn't help:

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I don't know what to try next to debug further!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your CocoaPods problem is that your server bails on the `User-Agent` that the CocoaPods script is sending. If you place the `curl -v` output from CocoaPods right next to the `curl -v` output from the command line, note the following difference:

```
user-agent: CocoaPods/1.10.1 cocoapods-downloader/1.4.0
```

vs

```
user-agent:  'CocoaPods/1.10.1 cocoapods-downloader/1.4.0'
```

The first one is from the command line, which works, and the second one is from CocoaPods, which causes your server to terminate the connection. If I’m reading the relevant RFCs correctly, the CocoaPods version technically satisfies the grammar defined for the `User-Agent` field, so that’s probably why this hasn’t ever been noticed before. Your server, however, seems to inspect the `User-Agent` more closely than others and rejects the one that CocoaPods sends.

So, my guess is that you can resolve this by making your server accept any `User-Agent`.

Comment: This was indeed the problem! In my podspec, I changed the source to `s.source       = { :http => "https://example.com/file.zip", :headers => [ "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" ] }` and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the ZIP file is being returned using HTTP/1.1 instead of HTTP/2 which CocoaPods is requiring. Older versions of TLS are no longer supported on some platforms so I'd recommend updating your web server/host to a platform that is using a more modern TLS.

Comment: If you run the command in Terminal with `-v` the server does use http2. `curl -f -L -o ~/Desktop/file.zip https://airturn.com/framework/test/AirTurnInterface.4.7.0-b.6.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2 -A 'CocoaPods/1.11.3 cocoapods-downloader/1.5.1' -v`